# $a < b$ and $c<d$ imply $a+c < b+d$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, proof-writing, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

> $a < b$ and $c<d$ imply $a+c < b+d$ when $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary
>   nonnegative integers.

I know that (assuming we include zero)
$$\begin{align*}
a<b \Leftrightarrow (\exists x\in \mathbb N)a + S(x) = b\\
c<d \Leftrightarrow (\exists y\in \mathbb N)c + S(y) = d
\end{align*}$$

And that's what I have done by using associative and conmutative properties:

$$(a+c)+(S(x)+S(y))\\=a+(c+S(x))+S(y)\\=a + (S(x)+c)+S(y)\\=(a+S(x)) + (c+S(y))\\= b + d$$

Also, we have that $S(x) + S(y) = S(S(x+y))$ by using addition definition recursively.

$x \land  y \in \mathbb{N} \implies S(x) \land S(y) \in \mathbb{N}^*$ 
where $\mathbb N^* =\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$

That means we could start with $(a + c) + 1 = b + d$ and could work with any $k \in \mathbb N^*$ that satisfies the expression for arbitrary $a, c, b, d \in \mathbb N$, thus $a+c < b+d$.

Is that proof valid in the context of naturals and Peano axioms?

Comment: You have to add that $S(x)+S(y)=S(S(x+y))$

Comment: More to the point, what you've done is valid, but your conclusion is $$(a+ c) + (S(x) + S(y)) = b + d$$while what you need to conclude is $a + c < b + d$. You have steps remaining.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could I use transivity here to complete the proof? I think the step remaining is the connection between $c$ and $d$ (i.e. $a < b < c < d$).

Comment: That is not the problem. It appears from where you started that you are defining $u < v$ by $(\exists x)u + S(x) = v$. So to match that definition and conclude that $a + c < b + d$, you need to show that there is some $w$ such that $(a + c) + S(w) = b + d$. Thus, what you need to show next is that $S(x) + S(y) = S(w)$ for some $w$. Federico has given an explicit expression for $w$, but for your purposes, all you need to show is that some $w$ works, not that explicit expression.

Comment: @PaulSinclair
I am a bit lost in what you said. How can I show that some $w$ works? By using induction? Since we are in naturals (where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$) we must use induction or is not always required? I've seen that this property is proved (where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$) by only using transitivity.

Comment: Induction is a handy tool for proving results in $\Bbb N$, but it is certainly not required. If all the results on which the proof in $\Bbb R$ you've seen relies have been proven in $\Bbb N$, then the exact same proof will work in $\Bbb N$. As for proving that $S(x) + S(y) = S(w)$ for some $w$, go back and look at the definition of "$+$". Depending on what development you are following, I'm pretty sure you will find that since neither $S(x)$ nor $S(y)$ is $0$, that the very defintion $S(x) + S(y)$ requires it to be $S(w)$ for some other value $w$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I've added these details to the question. I've used Peano axioms and the addition definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof is not quite complete.

In order to tshow that $a + c < b + d$, you need to show that there is something $z$ such that $$(b + d) + S(z) = a + c$$

all you have done is to show that

$$(b + d) + (S(x) + S(y)) = a + c$$

Fortunately, this problem is easily rectified, since you can show that $$S(x) + S(y) = S(S(x) + Y)$$

And hence you have the $z$ as need: $S(x) + y$